# C# No value from GET Request

Tags: c#, http, web, https

I have a WinForms Application in C# and I am trying to get the HTML-Code of a page via a GET-Request with the HTTPS-Protocol, but I am not able to get any value.

I have tried several solutions, but I can not fix this issue on my own.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.IO;

namespace sharpFUT
{
    public partial class frmShapfut : Form
    {
        string HTMLCode;

        public frmShapfut()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                HTMLCode = await getHTMLCode(tbxPlayerURL.Text);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }

            MessageBox.Show(HTMLCode);
        }

        private async Task<string> getHTMLCode(string url)
        {
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                AllowAutoRedirect = true
            };

            
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);

            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9");

            var result = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you think, from the information you've posted, that we will be able to tell you the answer?

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: I do not get any error, that is something that frustrates me aswell

Comment: @CaiusJard I am here to ask for help I am not asking for a direct solution.

Comment: @CaiusJard Which info is lacking in this post? Tell me.

Comment: Is this URl an api endpoint or just a webpage url?

Comment: Its just a webpage URL, I am trying to get the HTML-Code

Comment: If the webpage is using the HTTPS protocol, it might expect you to authorize / authenticate the request, by using the Authorize header.

Comment: Ok, I will try to implement this - Thank you!

Comment: But I am not trying to authorize myself (login) , I only want the HTML Code from the site

Comment: @infinitecodes your code is not the problem. it looks as if the url you're trying to open causes the issues. I tried your code with 'https://www.google.com' and several other https urls and all of them worked like a charm.

Comment: The site im trying to get the html code is: https://www.futwiz.com/de/fifa21/player/joshua-kimmich/20772

Comment: Works for me.. ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/tA52i.png

Comment: Yep for me too!

Comment: Ok i will try again

Comment: Okay, It works now, but when I try to output HTMLCode which should have the Data returned from getHTMLCode(), nothing happens.